# Mockery testing constructor call, new keyword

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I have a class name as a string property. One method (`fetchObject`) creates new instance of this class. I would like to test this method with PHPUnit and Mockery.

That's the code

```
class Maker
{
    private $_className = 'Article';

    public function fetchObject( $array )
    {
        return new $this->_className( $array );
    }
}
```

I tried something like this

```
$data = array( 'title' => 'Amazing title' );
$article = m::mock( 'Article', array( $data ) );

$maker= new Maker;
$result = $maker->fetchObject( array() );
```

Test works but I'm not sure if it checks for constructor call and I don't know how to check if param was passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would mock the Maker() class, and ensure it returned from the mock, the object you are looking for.

The other option I have done to test things like this, is to simply test Maker and call the fetchObject() routine with a given class expectation, and then test with an InstanceOf check that the returned object is of the desired class.

Comment: Thank you @steven. I made up simple class that I set in $_className like you wrote in second solution. In addition it's constructor sets $array as property so I can check if Maker is passing it.